# How to convert a float with exponent to a number without the exponent?

Tags: c#, variables

I want to write a program in C# that writes a `float` variable in text file like this:

```
.08937938030298
```

but at the moment it is printing it like this,

```
1.338527E+09
```

How can I convert that?

Comment: Different formating options for `double` are described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3hfd35ad%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Can you please share what code you have right now?  What does your print statement look like?

Comment: `float`s in C# are four bytes in length: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx.  The `precision` is 7 decimals, but that's another matter entirely.

Comment: timeStamp = ts_sec + ts_usec / 1000000 - floatstart;

Answer (score 1):

The [`float`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b1e65aza.aspx) numeric type only supports 24 bits for the size of the mantissa (i.e. the `1.338527` part in `1.338527E+09` or the number without the exponent). In other words,  numbers greater than `2^24` (roughly numbers with 8 digits) need to be represented using an exponent (i.e. `E+09`) which the have 7 bits of precision, or up to `2^7`. What you want to do is technically not possible since a `float` does not contain enough information to display that many digits in the mantissa.

You should try using a [`double`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/678hzkk9.aspx) which supports up to `2^48` which is roughly 14 digits of mantissa.